# Cannot access MS Access database using GridView (ASP.net)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, database, ms-access-2010

I am a beginner with ASP.net. I am using Microsoft Access Database. I am not getting any error, still, I cant display my data from the database.

My .aspx file is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="delivered.aspx.cs" Inherits="delivered" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <title>Delivered Works</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/StyleSheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="index.aspx"style="text-decoration:none;color:black;"><h1 style="font-family:Brush Script Std;font-size:54pt;">Boutique Manager</h1></a>
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:GridView>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My .aspx.cs file is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class delivered : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
      OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
      protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
         conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\000silpa\boutique\database\Boutique.accdb";

          try
              {

               OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\000silpa\boutique\database\Boutique.accdb");
               con.Open();
               OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select PhNo,Names,Cloth from customer where status="delivered", con");
               OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               GridView1.DataSource = dr;
               GridView1.DataBind();
              }
         catch (Exception ex)
              {

              }
         }
      }
```

My Database screenshot is:
[image]

Comment: When you debug, can you see that your reader has proper data? If yes, then try to set the datatable as the source of your gridview instead of DataReader itself.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Does your reader has any row? Put a breakpoint on cmd.ExecuteReader() and in quick what check if your reader has any row. By watching dr.HasRows, see if it is true.